# How to add Numbers In Arrays format if we have a word in 3 files using nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, for-loop, object, fs

I want to ask a question, what is it, I have three files, if there is a Word COMMON in those files  then it should be printed like this [1,2 3], otherwise, if there is a word in 1 and 2 then it should be printed like this [1 2] , I Tried to PUSH ARRAY  but it's not happening
Here Is My Code:

```
 let Page1data = filtered.map((val) => {
      let data = {};
      if (Page1.includes(val)) {
        data[val] = ["1"];
      }
    
      if (Page2.includes(val)) {
        data[val] = ["2"];
      }
      if (Page3.includes(val)) {
        data[val] = ["3"];
      }
      return data;
    });
    
    console.log(Page1data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, the problem is with your declaration.
`.push()` is for arrays not for objects. You have declared your `data` variable as an object.

You should use:

```
let data = [];
```

instead of

```
let data = {};
```

So it's going to look like this:

```
let data = [];
  if (Page1.includes(val)) {
    data.push("1");
  }
```

etc...